# argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" & expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class House {
private:
    char name[20];
    char date[10];
    float width;
    float height;
    float age;
public:
    void set(char n[20], char d[10], float w, float h, float a) {
        name = n;
        date = d;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        age = a;
    }

    void get() {
        std::cout << name << ", " << age << " (" << width << "x" << height <<
            ")" << ", age = " << age << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    House shop;
    shop.set("Shop", "2000.10.10", 200.5, 100.4, 10.0);
    return 0;
}
```

The picture shows my errors in debugging:
[image]

I know that I can use `std::string`, but in this program I want to use `char string[n]`
How to fix my mistakes?

Comment: `char n[20]` implies that the array `n` can be modified, written to. But you are passing a string literal that can't be written to. Make it `void set(const char* n, ...)` Further, arrays are not assignable - `name = n;` won't compile, no matter what type `n` is. In C++, use `std::string` for your string manipulation needs. If for some reason you insist on working with char arrays, see `strcpy` et al. Note also that `"2000.10.10"` won't fit into `char date[10]` - there's no room for the terminating NUL character.

Comment: Write a wrapper around your `char string[n]` so you can use the wrapper object as an object.  Then you can implement the methods and operators to give it the behaviors that you are trying to use which do not exist on a ol' C style array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use `std::string` instead. It's easier and safer.

But if you *must* use arrays, keep in mind that you cannot assign an array to another like that. What you must instead do is copy elements from one array to another. Since you're dealing with char arrays, the obvious solution is to use `strcpy`:

```
#include <cstring>

void set(const char n[20], const char d[10], float w, float h, float a) {
    strcpy(name, n);
    strcpy(date, d);
    width = w;
    height = h;
    age = a;
}
```

Notice how I made the char array arguments `const`: that's because array arguments to functions are really actually pointers in disguise, and you can't legally assign a literal to a non `const` pointer (at least not without enabling some kind of compiler specific option to allow dangerous deprecated conversions).

This, however, is potentially dangerous: it assumes that the input array is null terminated, and also that there are not more characters in the source that can fit in the destination. That includes the null terminator, which C++ will helpfully put at the end of any char array literal: so, a string like `"2000.10.10"` actually needs *11* characters, because of the hidden `\0` at the end, and missing that `\0` will cause a lot of trouble down the line because every C string function assumes it is there (and if it isn't, you're in undefined behaviour territory).

For all those reasons, using char arrays is a minefield, so *please*  use `std::string`.

Comment: Note also that the calling code passes `"2000.10.10"` for `d` argument, whereby `strcpy(date, d)` will cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: I still can't write the next line: `shop.set("Shop", "2000.10.10", 200.5, 100.4, 10.0);`

Comment: @np. `"2000.10.10"`  is too big to fit in a `char[10]` because of the null terminator (you always need one more character than you think you need).

Comment: Even if I write `shop.set("Shop", "22.10.10", 200.5, 100.4, 10.0);`, nothing has changed

Comment: `char d[10]` this makes `d` a `char*`. To pass a c-style array the syntax is `char (&d)[10]` - but that's irrelevant the relevant part is `d` is a `char*` and you try to pass a constant string to it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a paragraph about const correctness.

Comment: Yes, hence why I've updated my answer to talk about `const`.